# GroupBy and merge into a single list in java

Tags: lambda, java-8, collectors

Java 8 provides a groupingBy function in Collectors, but it gives a map of elements. I need to convert the map into a single list.

Also it returns the result, but instead what I want is to perform the grouping operation to the list itself so that I do not have to reassign it, as reassigning is not possible in a lambda expression.

How can I achieve this?

I want to achieve this:

```
Map<String, List<Node>> nodeListGrouped = nodeList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(node -> node.getGroupName()));
```

convert nodeListGrouped into a single List

But nodeListGrouped.values() returns Collection(List)

Comment: `Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toMap(whatevermappings), map -> {whatever transformations from map to List you have in mind})`?

Comment: and btw you are a member for 4 years here, you do understand that unless you provide details/example this will get closed as unclear right?

Comment: so your problem is that `values` returns a `Collection<List<Node>>` and you want a `List<Node>`?

Comment: yes and also i cannot reassign the groupedList as it gives error "list should be final or effectively final"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for (I have not compiled this though )

```
List<Node> list = 
         nodeList.stream()
                 .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                     Collectors.groupingBy(Node::getGroupName),
                     map -> map.values()
                               .stream()
                               .flatMap(List::stream)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList())
));
```

Comment: it says collectionAndThen is undefined for Colectors, I tried collectingAndThen , and then it says to cast it again and again

Comment: @ManojMajumdar my bad, it's `collectingAndThen`, edited

Comment: Thanks Man!! That was fast!! Help appreciated

Comment: I'm I missing something here? you're grouping and then flattening back to how the list was initially which makes this entire pipeline unnecessary.

Comment: @Aominè oh shoot! :| totally a brain fart here, need to ask the OP about details...

Comment: @ManojMajumdar need more details from you, the way it is here, I am taking the initial `List`, group and after transform it into the initial List, how it was. This is entirely not needed, may be you can provide some more details here

Comment: Hi Eugene, it is grouping the elements as needed, may be i am not able to follow the comment given by @Aominè, how else can we achieve the same without using flatMap ?

Comment: @ManojMajumdar print `nodeList` before the stream pipeline and print `list` after the stream pipeline and see if you can find any difference. the answer is no difference. what exactly do you want? there's no point in grouping just to flatten the all the lists back to how it was initially.

Comment: @Aominè there is a difference in the order of the nodes. For example, if we have three orders (A, B, C) then after the pipeline is executed, we will get a different order (maybe the same but not always).

Comment: @marsouf then why not just do `Collections.shuffle(nodeList);` if you just want to randomise the order...Anyhow, don't think that's what the OP wants unless otherwise said.

Comment: @Aominè I agree, i am still confused of what the OP exactly needs.

Comment: @marsouf in this case 100%, always, shuffle, instead if this ugly pipeline

Comment: @Aominè the effect of this operation is not exactly shuffling, as after `groupingBy`, the members of each group are adjacent to each other, even if the order of the groups is undefined. So I’d say, unpredictable group order might be allowed, but not required by the OP, so `nodeList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Node::getGroupName))` would be a valid alternative (but `nodeList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Node::getGroupName).reversed())` too)…

Comment: @Holger I want exactly the same, I do not want to group the elements, I just want to make the elements in a group adjacent to each other and I thought, the way to achieve this is to group the elements and then convert it into a list.

Comment: @ManojMajumdar that’s a working solution. If the type of the `Node::getGroupName` has an order (like `String` or numbers), you could sort the list by that property instead, like shown in my previous comment. But even for properties without a natural order, you could use `sort`, e.g. `HashMap<Object,Integer> groups = new HashMap<>(); l.sort(Comparator.comparing(o -> groups.merge(o.getGroupName(),groups.size(),(a,b)->a)));`. But grouping and assembling a new list is a valid solution too (and preferable if you don’t want to modify the source list).

Answer (score 3):

flattening the map values from `Collection<List<Node>>` into a `List<Node>` is *almost* certainly not what you want as that essentially renders the same result as the initial list; and if you indeed want to get a `List<Node>` as the result then *don't do anything* as that's what the initial list already offers.

You definitely need to rethink what exactly you want to accomplish. Ask your self why do I need to group just to end up with the same result as the initial list? once you find that answer maybe you'll realise you didn't need to do this at all or there may be other approaches to accomplish your task better.

Comment: I completely agree !

Comment: @Aominè, I just want to group the elements, so that they come adjacent to each other and then just display the whole list of elements(nodes)

Comment: @ManojMajumdar Right, it would have been nice if you mentioned this initially in your post or at least created a method indicating what the intention is for readability. Anyway, another shorter and more readable option would just be to clone the initial list then sort it by the group name as suggested by #Holger under your answer. Or if you don’t mind altering the initial list just sort that by group name to get adjacent elements. That said, ultimately it’s your choice with what approach you go with.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the benefit of converting the map back to a list, because you will lose the grouping key. What you can do is convert back the map to a `List<Map.Entry<String, List<Node>>>` by calling the `entrySet()` method and not `values()`.